# How to determine the last execution of a job in quartz.net?

Tags: .net, scheduling, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET to schedule some jobs that monitor hardware parameters (e.g. cpu and ram usage). In each execution they retrieve the usage and write it to an xml-file. The jobs are parametrized with a start time, end time and an interval. This looks like following:

```
    IScheduler scheduler = await _SchedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    // Build the job
    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonitoringJob>()
        .WithIdentity("identity")
        .Build();

    // Build trigger to run every 5 seconds with start and end time
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("identity")
        .StartAt(startTime)
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
        .EndAt(endTime)
        .Build();

    // Schedule job
    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

As the job is executed for the last time due to expiration, I'd like to have a notification to be able to update my UI and show a message there.

I already tried to accomplish this using the ListenerManager together with a custom implementation of IJobListener. Unfortunately this interface only defines methods like JobToBeExecuted, JobExecutionVetoed and JobWasExecuted. This does not help me to figure out when the job was executed for the last time or has completed at all.

Does anybody have an idea on how to figure out the job completion?

Comment: Job doesn't have a fire time, a Trigger does. And Trigger has .GetPreviousFireTimeUtc()